# Plaid Link for Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, plaid

I'd like to use [Plaid](https://plaid.com/) Link on Android application. I try to embed some javascript in WebView as in [tutorial](https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#glossary) :

```
<form id="some-id" method="POST" action="/authenticate"></form>

<!-- To use Link with longtail institutions on Connect, set the
data-longtail attribute to 'true'. See the Parameter Reference for
additional documentation. -->
<script
        src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"
        data-client-name="Client Name"
        data-form-id="some-id"
        data-key="test_key"
        data-product="auth"
        data-env="tartan">
</script>
```

However the UI seems to be cut - the frame is too small and whole UI needs to be scrolled:
[image]

Is there anything that could fix that issue?

Comment: Hi @Adam i am trying to use plaid in my android application. Is there any plugin dependency available for android or not? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to this is that you need to request/set a height and width of the Webview otherwise it does not fill the parent.  If you do not set it large enough it cuts off the Plaid Link page.